# websphere application server 8.5.5 create very much connections to ldap

Tags: websphere

I have an websphere application running on wevsphere that validates about LDAP. In the monitoring of network traffic, I see many connections with LDAP queries: Is there a log where you can see the queries that this makes?

Comment: i´m using centos 7

Answer (score 0):

In LDAP, each authentication request is a bind operation, which establishes a connection to LDAP. So so each authentication request, a connection is created, and connection will be closed immediately. You will see one LDAP connection for each authentication request.